# Brute force attack?

Tags: login, security, hacks

I'm seeing this quite often:

[image]

No OS, same Browser, weird hostname -- they're definitely not real users. Can I do anything to take precautions before they do something?

Thanks!

Comment: You can restrict access to dashboard by IP. Basically, adding a captcha to login forms also helps against bruteforce attacks (by slowing them down to a crawl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an <del>app</del> plugin for that, [Limit Login Attempts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/limit-login-attempts/).

Some more info available in this wp beginner post: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-and-why-you-should-limit-login-attempts-in-your-wordpress/

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks as there is no referrer you could block the attempts with .htaccess.
Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*/wp-login\.php.*\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^-?$
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS]
```

There are different variations on that, you could even just trying using REQUEST_URI instead.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-login\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^-?$
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS]
```

Or if you're the only person logging into your site you could lock it down even more like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-login\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteRule .* http://example.com [R=301,L]
```

Where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is your static IP Address. Can be modified to just work for Class A, B, or C if you have a dynamic IP Address.

Where example.com is your TLD. That way they're just redirected to your home page.